# Do I need a custom adapter to fill this GridView? And if so, how do I make one?

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-adapter, android-gridview

I'm trying to fill a `GridView` with content that is being mapped to 2 objects by Retrofit.
I've already got the Retrofit part working, and I'm successfully receiving the data I need through it.

However, I'm not sure how to fill my `GridView` in this case, as I have mixed data types, and I'm nearly sure that because of that I need a custom adapter.
I was thinking of making a custom adapter based off `ArrayAdapter`, but I don't know how to implement it, and I've tried searching online but I still don't understand it very well.

My `GridView` is very basic at the moment (and to be honest I'm not sure it has all the required properties), but here it is:

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gv_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

</GridView>
```

My classes that have their data being mapped to them by Retrofit look like this:

`NewsAPI.java`:

```
public class NewsAPI {
    String status;
    String source;
    ArrayList<Articles> articles;

    public NewsAPI(String status, String source, ArrayList<Articles> articles) {
        this.status = status;
        this.source = source;
        this.articles = articles;
    }
}
```

`Articles.java`:

```
public class Articles {
    String title;
    String description;

    public Articles(String title, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is an example of the original JSON data I have before parsing through Retrofit.

```
{
"status": "ok",
"source": "techcrunch",
"sortBy": "top",
-"articles": [
-{
"author": "Darrell Etherington",
"title": "Six new Sun and Moon Pokémon evolutions revealed",
"description": "Pokémon Sun and Moon's release for 3DS rapidly approaches, and the Pokémon Company is unveiling eight new Pokémon unique to the new games, including six..",
"url": "http://social.techcrunch.com/2016/10/14/six-new-sun-and-moon-pokemon-evolutions-revealed/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/poke-compressor.gif?w=680&amp;h=400&amp;crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2016-10-14T14:29:12Z"
},
-{
"author": "Brian Heater",
"title": "That Nike-branded Apple Watch arrives October 28",
"description": "Maybe you’ve been waiting for the Nike+ version to arrive before running out to buy the Apple Watch Series 2. Because, you know, life is a marathon, not a..",
"url": "http://social.techcrunch.com/2016/10/14/nike-apple-watch/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/img_8919.jpg?w=764&amp;h=400&amp;crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2016-10-14T13:33:25Z"
},
-{
"author": "Darrell Etherington",
"title": "Iron Man offers to voice Mark Zuckerberg’s real-life Jarvis AI",
"description": "Facebook CEO Mark Zuckerberg sets an ambitious goal every year for himself, and this year it was to create an AI assistant for his home, modelled in part on..",
"url": "http://social.techcrunch.com/2016/10/14/iron-man-offers-to-voice-mark-zuckerbergs-real-life-jarvis-ai/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/91kwg8.jpg?w=764&amp;h=400&amp;crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2016-10-14T12:06:22Z"
},
-{
"author": "Natasha Lomas",
"title": "Instagram now has an app for Windows 10 tablets",
"description": "Instagram has expanded its app availability to users of tablets running Microsoft's Windows 10. The Facebook-owned, visual content social sharing platform..",
"url": "http://social.techcrunch.com/2016/10/14/instagram-now-has-an-app-for-windows-10-tablets/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/screen-shot-2016-10-14-at-12-49-56-pm.png?w=622&amp;h=400&amp;crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2016-10-14T11:10:47Z"
},
-{
"author": "Ingrid Lunden",
"title": "Spotify co-founder Martin Lorentzon steps down as chairman, CEO Daniel Ek steps up",
"description": "A changing of the guard is underway at Spotify, the streaming music service with 40 million paying users and over 100 million overall that competes with the..",
"url": "http://social.techcrunch.com/2016/10/14/spotify-co-founder-martin-lorentzon-steps-down-as-chairman-ceo-daniel-ek-steps-up/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/screen-shot-2014-05-21-at-11-19-55-am.png?w=764&amp;h=364&amp;crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2016-10-14T10:32:48Z"
},
-{
"author": "Natasha Lomas",
"title": "Softbank and Saudi Arabia’s PIF planning $100BN tech fund",
"description": "Softbank has announced it is creating a new global tech investment fund, seeded with $25 billion of its own money. The fund, which will be London, UK based --..",
"url": "http://social.techcrunch.com/2016/10/14/softbank-and-saudi-arabias-pif-planning-100bn-tech-fund/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/softbank-img.jpg?w=764&amp;h=400&amp;crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2016-10-14T08:33:08Z"
},
-{
"author": "Sarah Buhr",
"title": "GM’s car sharing company Maven hits the streets of San Francisco",
"description": "Maven, a car sharing company out of General Motors, is driving its way into San Francisco today. The announcement made late Thursday evening is one part of a..",
"url": "http://social.techcrunch.com/2016/10/13/gms-one-way-ride-startup-maven-hits-the-streets-of-san-francisco/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/gmmaven02.jpg?w=764&amp;h=400&amp;crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2016-10-14T04:00:54Z"
},
-{
"author": "Khaled \"Tito\" Hamze",
"title": "Crunch Report | Soylent Bars Are Getting Recalled",
"description": "Hyperloop One raises $50 million from DP World Group of Dubai, Soylent Bars are being recalled, Silicon Valley elites donate to controversial Prop Q,..",
"url": "http://social.techcrunch.com/2016/10/13/crunch-report-soylent-bars-are-getting-recalled/",
"urlToImage": "https://img.vidible.tv/prod/2016-10/13/580007b7869ea9143336a6ec_o_U_v1.jpg?w=764&#038;h=400",
"publishedAt": "2016-10-14T03:00:40Z"
},
-{
"author": "Rudina Seseri",
"title": "The AI disruption wave",
"description": "Information technology evolves through disruption waves. First the computer, then the web and eventually social networks and smartphones all had the power to..",
"url": "http://social.techcrunch.com/2016/10/13/the-ai-disruption-wave/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/gettyimages-4964795042560x-80.jpg?w=764&amp;h=400&amp;crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2016-10-14T03:00:39Z"
},
-{
"author": "John Mannes",
"title": "Returnly raises $3.2M to immediately refund your money after an online return",
"description": "Returning a product you bought online is inherently a statement of dislike, but smart retailers are quickly learning that they're far better off if they..",
"url": "http://social.techcrunch.com/2016/10/13/returnly-raises-3-2m-to-immediately-refund-your-money-after-an-online-return/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/gettyimages-495813985.jpg?w=764&amp;h=400&amp;crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2016-10-13T23:45:18Z"
}
]
}
```

Comment: You load Articles from two different API using retrofit and merge them together inside NewsAPI, and want to show them at the same level in your GridView all together? Did I get it right?

Comment: @MohsenMirhoseiniArgi No, I'm loading the JSON data from the same API, but the articles themselves are an array inside of the NewsAPI object. I've added an example of the JSON data to my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to a custom adapter and It is very simple!

Don't get confused by extra objects within your **NewsAPI**. You just want to show Articles in grid, so passing Articles ArrayList to your adapter is enough.

I prefer using `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`:

**your_activity.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/gv_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**item_article.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!--other elements-->

</LinearLayout>
```

You have to define your `Adapter` like this:

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java:**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ArticleViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Articles> articles;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Articles> articles) {
        this.articles = articles;
    }

    @Override
    public ArticleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_article, parent, false);
        return new ArticleViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ArticleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Articles article = articles.get(position);

        holder.setArticles(article);
        holder.bindData();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    public class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public final View view;
        Articles articles;

        public TextView author;

        public ArticleViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.view = view;

            author = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.author);
            // find other UI elements!
        }

        public void setArticles(Articles articles) {
            this.articles = articles;
        }

        public void bindData() {
            author.setText(articles.getTitle());
        }
    }

}
```

and you have to setup RecyclerView like this:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.gv_content);

GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(newsAPI.getArticles()));
```

I hope it helps :)